# Tablesorter combining sortList with disabled columns

Tags: sorting, tablesorter

I feel sure this is a simple answer but as a rookie I'm failing to see it. I just want a table to have column 0 and 2 disabled from the sort, then the default sort to be column 1. Two separate commands, but while they work individually they seem to clash together.
I can have my columns 0 and 2 disabled and the table works perfectly. Or I can have my initial sort set to column 2 and the table works perfectly. But when put together my remaining sortable columns will only allow one click, they cannot be toggled acending, descending.

Can anyone help, as I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/81/):

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    sortList : [[ 1, 0 ]],
    headers : {
        0 : { sorter: false },
        2 : { sorter: false }
    }

});​
```

Comment: That's brilliant, works perfectly. What did you do differently, what was I missing? Thanks so much.