# JQuery tablesorter disable column

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to disable the first column of a table with the JQuery plugin tablesorter 2.0.5

While it does disable, I can't sort other columns properly anymore. I can only click once on a column and then have to click once on another column to be able to click again (still only once), as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667572/tablesorter-combining-sortlist-with-disabled-columns).

I have followed [this first example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html) and [this other example](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html)

and here's the code I include in the php view

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
    headers: { 
        0: {sorter: false}
    } 
    }); 
});

</script>';
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo you could share? The second example you shared uses class names and that will only work with tablesorter v2.0.11+ from [this fork on github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter).

Comment: @Mottie Right, somehow I didn't read the 2nd example right! I tried to create a demo with jsfiddle (never used it before) but can't seem to find a link to the source code of 2.0.5 and it doesn't work to just copy it in the js window. I tried upgrading to version 2.3.11 but I'm getting the same problem in my application

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is [a jsFiddle demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/113/)

Your code looks okay, except that the `language` attribute is no longer necessary, so I'm not sure where you might be having your problem.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
    headers: { 
        0: {sorter: false}
    } 
    }); 
});
</script>';
```

Things to check would be:

1. Ensure there is only one copy of jQuery running
2. Ensure that the tablesorter script is loaded after jQuery (the script tag should be after it)
3. Make sure that `table` is the correct target for tablesorter. You may need to add an ID or class name to the table then target it, e.g. `$("#mytable")`.
4. Check your page for errors - press F12, go to the console then reload the page.

Comment: 1. There is only one jquery file containing the sources, named jquery-1.3.2.js

It has been updated (not by me) as it is written "jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2" in the comments at the beginning of the file. Does the version have an impact? When I tried setting the demo, the table would not sort at all if I chose 1.3.2, and would work ok with the other versions and I see also that the demo you made uses tablesorter 2.3.11

2. The tablesorter code is part of a bigger file, which is indeed loaded after the jquery-1.3.2.js script

3. Still same problem with an id

4. No error